# Workflow between Blender and Max

Tags: export

I've recently started to work for a company that uses 3ds max and Vray as their main softwares. I know 3ds max, but it has an incredibly slow workflow and things need to be done quickly, so I run to Blender to model, than export to FBX, import into 3ds max and apply the vray materials.

It works well, unless they require modifications in the models, then I have to do the whole dance again: change, export, apply mats, etc, multiple times until it gets approved. I can't use linked files because they use custom scripts that won't work with them.

So, my question is: is there a better way to achieve what I need? Maybe a faster workflow? Is there a way to set vray mats in Blender and then export to max?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use 3DS Max only for rendering? I believe there is a VRay plugin for Blender, maybe that way you could skip whole export process. Would that speed things up? As it stands this question sounds too vague and broad.

Comment: No, actually I send over to them via a custom 3ds max script and later it gets rendered by someone else. I wish I could do everything in Blender, but I need to export to max with vray so they can do their thing hehe

Comment: My advice would be to get good with Max, so you can be as productive there as in Blender. Chances are you will find you can be even more productive and faster in Max.. My other advice if you need to stick with both Blender and Max is to automate the pipeline with python. I don't think there is much else you can do..

Comment: @Jerryno I guess I'll have to find a way through python. There's no way I'm modeling in that prehistoric software.

Comment: There is nothing prehistoric about it, 99.9% of it's code is newer than Blender's. It is Blender who is relying on prehistoric code and non-optimized open-source libraries. I think you have serious prejudice, have a look how fast modelling in 3Dmax is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cx64lj5aboo and maybe you can be faster than with Blender, since Max's tools are more advanced and better optimized.

Comment: I may have expressed myself wrongly, my problem with max is not tool quality, but the software itself is terribly slow. I often open a max file and go to the bathroom to try to optimize my life a bit for instance hehe. No prejudice here, I work with it everyday. (btw, it's been a while since I modeled anything on it... it has definitely improved wonders on that matter, judging by the video)